# How do I use the Jquery Name Badge /text avatar plugin with angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to generate name badges/ text avater in an angular JS, ionic  app.

```
            .controller("myCtrl",function($scope, userService){
                 userService.getUsers().then(function(users){
                    $scope.users = users.data;

                    $(function(){
                        $('.name').nameBadge({

                         // boder options
                          border: {
                          color: '#ddd',
                          width: 3
                            },

                      // an array of background colors.
                       colors: ['#a3a948', '#edb92e', '#f85931', '#ce1836', '#009989'],

                       // text color
                           text: '#fff',

                       // avatar size
                       size: 48,

                       // avatar margin
                        margin: 5,

                        // disable middle name 
                        middlename: true,

                        // force uppercase
                         uppercase: false

                          });
                          });
                          });
                      })
```

my view looks like this :

```
      <ion-item class="item-avatar " collection-repeat="item in users">

        <div class="name">{{item.username}}</div>
       </ion-item>
```

The problem is, It is showing iu which is the initials of item and username, rather than returning extracting the initials of the real username.

The Jquery namebadge Plugin is :

```
                      (function ($) {
$.fn.nameBadge = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        border: {
            color: '#ddd',
            width: 3
        },
        colors: ['#a3a948', '#edb92e', '#f85931', '#ce1836', '#009989'],
        text: '#fff',
        size: 72,
        margin: 5,
        middlename: true,
        uppercase: false
    }, options);
    return this.each(function () {
        var elementText = $(this).text();
        var initialLetters = elementText.match(settings.middlename ? /\b(\w)/g : /^\w|\b\w(?=\S+$)/g);
        var initials = initialLetters.join('');
        $(this).text(initials);
        $(this).css({
            'color': settings.text,
            'background-color': settings.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.colors.length)],
            'border': settings.border.width + 'px solid ' + settings.border.color,
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'font-family': 'Arial, \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, sans-serif',
            'font-size': settings.size * 0.4,
            'border-radius': settings.size + 'px',
            'width': settings.size + 'px',
            'height': settings.size + 'px',
            'line-height': settings.size + 'px',
            'margin': settings.margin + 'px',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'text-transform' : settings.uppercase ? 'uppercase' : ''
        });
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Show us your service code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Move your plugin code into and angular directive (look here for how to do that https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Then use this angular dependency ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate ), $interpolate, to get the value of what is inside the divs. Use it on this line of the plugin: `var elementText = $(this).text();`

Do not forget to inject $interpolate inside your directive.

Comment: Thank you, do you have idea, how I could implement $interploate to change $(this).text()

Comment: I cannot find any concise examples of people using it for the same case. Another possible way would be to surround `var elementText = $(this).text();` inside a `$timeout(function(){
  //the code which needs to run after dom rendering
})`. This would run the function after the DOM and Angular has rendered which would hopefully mean that the inside of your div would be pure text and not `{{item.username}}`. Tinker with that, it could be an easier solution.